# iOS: play a video on every startup of universal application

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, startup, ios-universal-app

I'm working on a universal iOS application. On the startup a short intro video should be displayed, but I can't figure out how to handle it for both device types correctly. It is a master-detail-application. So when and where should I load my video to view it on startup?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just want to throw my two cents in. It is not a good user experience if you force your users to sit through a video everytime they start the app. Perhaps just make it easy to find and start instead of forcing everyone to waste precious time waiting to use your app.

Comment: Well, this might be correct, but it's not really my choice...

Comment: Again just my two cents :) and a very very generalized statement. Happy Coding :)

Comment: The video is only about 3 seconds long and it really is not my decision to make it like that, but I have to do it. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want it just on initial launch, put play code in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Or if you want to play every time the app becomes active

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I thought about that, too. But how am I gonna add my Movie Player to the application? Do I have to create a navigation controller first?